# Unbinding std::bind in c++

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a number of function pointers bound with their respective class objects:

```
ExampleClass EO;
std::function<void()> Example=std::bind(&ExampleClass::ExampleFunction, &EO);
```

However, I'd like to 'unbind' these at a later point, specifically to identify the specific class which each of the 'std::function's relate to.

```
auto Unbind(std::function<void()> &Example)->void
{
  //Find which object &Example is bound with (in this case EO/ExampleClass)
}
```

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: This is not possible. Although you can retrieve a `std::function`'s target, the target type is the unknowable type of the bind expression, which does not have an interface to retrieve the information you're after.

Comment: @KerrekSB That's an answer :)

Comment: @KerrekSB could you provide an example use of std::function::target?

Comment: @barbrac: [See here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::function` performs type erasure. As per the name, it erases the real underlying types from the interface.

There is no way back from there.

If you want to preserve the type of the target object, then `std::mem_fn` might be what you want:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn

Comment: `target` does provide a "way back" from the type erasure. The problem is `std::bind`.

Comment: @KerrekSB target_type is a `std::type_info` though, not a type. So the only thing it can be used for is comparing against a list of pre-computed known types. I don't think it qualifies as a "way back" in the sense that I meant it (i.e. deducible). I will accept that it is "a step on the way back" :)

Comment: Well, yes, you need to know the type you expect, but to be clear, `target` (not `target_type`) returns an actual pointer to a real object (or null).

Comment: @RichardHodges std::mem_fn does not help in this case, as the function receiving the function pointer will not know which class it derives from or the potential classes it could derive from.
I think the only solution is to use a std::tuple as a container, and to pair each function pointer with its host object

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it with a `function` object.

A possibility is to construct a wrapper in which to store the reference to the method and the object.

Something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename Fn>
struct MemberFunctionPointer {
  MemberFunctionPointer(T* ref, Fn fn) : m_ref(ref),
                                          m_method(fn) { }

  template<typename... Args>
  auto operator()(Args&&... args) {
    return (m_ref->*m_method)(std::forward<Args...>(args)...);
  }

  T* m_ref = nullptr;  // a reference (pointer) to the object instance
  Fn m_method = nullptr;  // a reference to the function method
};
```

*Note:* this is just a scratch. You should add a more sophisticated interface. Moreover a helper function in order to create a `MemberFunctionPointer` object could be useful as well.

You can pass that kind of object instead of a simply `function`.

```
struct Foo {
  void bar() {
    // something
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Foo f;
  MemberFunctionPointer<Foo, decltype(&Foo::bar)> method(&f, &Foo::bar);

  method();  // call the method on the object f.

  assert(&f == method.get_obj_reference());
  return 0;
}
```